# How do FRAM oil filters stand up to their competition?

Tags: oil-change

My friend is telling me that Wix is a better oil filter. He says they don't use paper, and that the intake holes are bigger. I just [bought a TG16 (which is the expensive FRAM filter)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0009IR0A6). Is there any objective studies done on these two? How do I know paper is worse than whatever Wix using? How do I know that hole size matters at all?

Is there a consumer reviews or something that can advise my purchase?

Answer (score 4):

Check out [Oil Filters Revealed](http://minimopar.knizefamily.net/oilfilters/index.html).  The Tough Guard is [described](http://minimopar.knizefamily.net/oilfilters/opinions.html) by the author as 'not too bad', but I wouldn't use one on any of my vehicles.  Nothing good is said about the rest of the FRAM line.  The WIX is described as 'another quality oil filter similar in design to the Purolator', though the 2008 version that was taken apart did have a paper filter element.  There are also plenty of tear down videos on Youtube.

Personally, if I had to choose between the FRAM and the WIX, I would go for the WIX for the metal end caps if nothing else.  I buy the K&N filters with the nut.  It's handy on my vehicles.  If it wasn't for the nut, I'd save a couple bucks and go for the Mobil 1.

Comment: My grandfather used to swear by Fram (got excellent results), but I read a lot of bad about them.  My car with the low oil filter I use Mobil1 simply because I know it fits in there with the downpipe (a K&N w/nut wouldn't have enough room to remove).  The other car with high mounted filter I use Toyota branded (not sure who makes them) as they definitely have the anti-drainback valve.  Tried a Mobil1 on that car and had knock on every start while it was installed so I presume the Mobil1 doesn't have the anti-drainback valve?